# what is eth0@if1092 mean in kubernetes pod using ip -a command

Tags: kubernetes

I am execute `ip a` command in kubernetes pod:

```
/ # ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
1091: eth0@if1092: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:1e:b8:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.30.184.13/21 brd 172.30.191.255 scope global eth0
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

what is meaning of `eth0@if1092` ? some article said that the `1092` is the pair sequence no, is there any according? what is `if` stand for?

Answer (score 2):

`if1092` corresponds to `1092th` interface on the root network interface. `if` is short form of `interface`. The other end of this interface in pod network namespace is attached to a `veth` interface in root network namespace. The index on that `veth` interface should also be `1092`. You can check that by running `ip a` as `root` in the node where the pod is running.